# ExtJS:: How to add specific "specialkey event" for comma to numberfield?

Tags: javascript, extjs

If want to my nubmerfield take "," and covert it to "." on key up. Numberfield doesn't allow to input "," in it. And I want to handle "specialkey" and add "." manually. But "," isn't special key. How to add it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert ',' into '.' on key up, why do you want to handle it with 'specialkey' event? Why don't you use 'keyup' event?

Here's an example:

```
Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody () ,
    width: 300 ,
    height: 150 ,
    title: 'It works!' ,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield' ,
        enableKeyEvents: true ,
        fieldLabel: 'Age' ,
        listeners: {
            keyup: function (nf, evt) {
                // 188 is ','
                if (evt.getKey () == 188) {
                    nf.setRawValue (nf.getRawValue () + '.');
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}).show ();
```

Otherwise you can use **disableKeyFilter** property to allow the user to insert special chars, like ,.&*% etc. and then find a way out to replace ',' with '.'

By the way, if you want to handle ',' with **specialkey** event, here's a trick:

```
Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody () ,
    width: 300 ,
    height: 150 ,
    title: 'It works!' ,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield' ,
        enableKeyEvents: true ,
        fieldLabel: 'Age' ,
        listeners: {
            keyup: function (nf, evt) {
                // 188 is ','
                if (evt.getKey () == 188) {
                    // Fire 'specialkey' up passing ','
                    nf.fireEvent ('specialkey', nf, evt);
                }
            } ,
            specialkey: function (nf, evt) {
                // Here we are!
                alert (evt.getKey ());
            }
        }
    }]
}).show ();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
specialkey: function(field, e){
              // e.HOME, e.END, e.PAGE_UP, e.PAGE_DOWN,
              // e.TAB, e.ESC, arrow keys: e.LEFT, e.RIGHT, e.UP, e.DOWN
              if (e.getKey() == e.TAB) {
                    //Do specific action
              }
        }
```

Comment: It's aways good practice to add an explanation with code answers